# My Delegate method is not getting Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I just started learning objective-c, i was breaking my head why this below simple code for protocols and delegates is not working, please clarify me why this is delegate method is not getting called. Thanks in advance.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include "secondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<ConverterDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) secondViewController *secondview;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *msgtext;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *converbutton;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize msgtext,converbutton,secondview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.secondview=[[secondViewController alloc]init];
    secondview.delegate=self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)convertToFahrenheit:(int)celsius{

    float fah = ((1.8)*celsius)+32;
    msgtext.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"the %i deg Celsius             equal to %.2f Fah",celsius,fah];
}
@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ConverterDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)convertToFahrenheit:(int)celsius;
@end

@interface secondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ConverterDelegate> delegate;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;
- (IBAction)convert:(id)sender;

@end
```

secondViewController.m

```
#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface secondViewController ()

@end

@implementation secondViewController
@synthesize textfield,delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}    

- (IBAction)convert:(id)sender {
    [delegate convertToFahrenheit:[textfield.text intValue]];
    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

I was totally confused why my delegate method is not getting called. I a newbie to Objective c please help me.

Comment: refer this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-custom-delegates--mobile-10848  and also http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/delegate.html

Comment: Explain how you're testing - particularly how you're displaying the 2 different view controllers...

Comment: i have first view with a label and a button, when the button was clicked it will move to the second view via modal segue. In second view i have textfield and a button, when the user put some value into the text field and press the button the second view was dismissed and the calculated value should be displayed in the first view label.

Comment: Hi Wain, Thanks for your timely response, When i add the below code to viewController.m it works fine, but why we need to add this code        - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    secondViewController *addViewControler = [segue destinationViewController];
    [addViewControler setDelegate:self];
}

Comment: apparently there is nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code will fulfil your requirements.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Calculation.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CalculationDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *msgtext;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField * inputField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *converbutton;

-(IBAction)convertMetod:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize msgtext,converbutton,inputField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)convertMetod:(id)sender
{
    Calculation * CalculationObj = [[Calculation alloc] init];
    CalculationObj.delegate = self;
    [CalculationObj convertCelToFaher:[inputField.text intValue]];

}
-(void)showTheAns:(NSString *)ans
{
    NSLog(@"delegate method called");
    msgtext.text = ans;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

Calculation.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@protocol CalculationDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void) showTheAns:(NSString *) ans;
@end

@interface Calculation : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic) id <CalculationDelegate> delegate;
-(void)convertCelToFaher:(int)celsius;
@end
```

Calculation.m

```
#import "Calculation.h"
@implementation Calculation
@synthesize delegate;
-(void)convertCelToFaher:(int)celsius
{

    float fah = ((1.8)*celsius)+32;

    [delegate showTheAns:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"the %i deg Celsius             equal to %.2f Fah",celsius,fah]];
}
@end
```